# How can I run a php file in bash by calling its filename only and not prefixing the php binary?

Tags: linux, bash, input, file-types

```
chmod +x ./file.php
./file.php
```

Is there any way to have it execute as if I typed

```
php ./file.php
```

Perhaps by adjusting bash's default input function?

Or is there a file types application that detects a ".php" or ".txt" and edits it with a particular program when the file is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the "shebang" at the start of the file:

```
#!/path/to/php
```

As the first line of the file (no whitespace added!) should do the trick

Comment: I get the error:-bash: ./tv-verify.php: /usr/bin/php^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory https://i.imgur.com/hEXGg1D.png

Comment: @BradyOsborne The error is self-explanatory: the file declares that it should be interpreted by `/usr/bin/php`, but that file doesn't exist on your system. You can get the interpreter's path with `which php`, but you should investigate why PHP is not in its standard location at `/usr/bin/php`.

Comment: @gronostaj My php is at /usr/bin/php and I used which php to find it. See this https://i.imgur.com/lgMKxPm.png

Comment: @gronostaj The problem was that my file was using DOS line endings instead of UNX, changed that and fixed! Thanks!

Comment: But if you use a shebang, the shebang line will be displayed on the screen before script output if you try to run that script from the web. So if you need a script that should be usable both from the web and from the command line (I had quite a few of such use cases), you cannot use shebang :(.

Comment: @raj What do you mean by "run script from the web"?

Comment: Assume your script is `/var/www/script.php` . You may run it from command line with `php /var/www/script.php` but you may also access it from the web as `http://yoursite/script.php` (assuming `/var/www` is the top-level directory of your web server). That's what I mean.

Comment: PHP typically accepts `#` as remark - maybe must be enabled in `php.ini`

Comment: But the shebang line is **outside** the PHP code - it must be the very first line in the file - that's the problem. So it is treated just as literal text to send to browser. The Apache PHP module would need to recognize such line and handle it specially, but it doesn't have such a feature.